# Multiple patterns not working while writing the logs to console

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

my requirement is to write the different logs to the console which needs to have a different pattern.

I've used multiple appenders and used a separate logger but it's not taking the pattern which I've given for the appender instead it's taking another pattern.

Below is the `log4j2.properties`

```
name = PropertiesConfig

appenders = console, console1

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %t %-5p %c{6}:%L - %m%n

appender.console1.type = Console
appender.console1.name = STDOUT1
appender.console1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console1.layout.pattern = %m%n

loggers = rolling
logger.rolling.name = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling

#Configure module specific
logger.org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector = info
logger.com.test.test1 = fine
logger.com.test.test1.service.impl.RSStd=info

#configure rootLogger and attach all the appenders to it
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

logger.performancelog.name = PERFORMANCE_LOG
logger.performancelog.additivity = false
logger.performancelog.level = info
logger.performancelog.appenderRef.console1.ref = STDOUT1
```

Every time it's picking this pattern

```
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %t %-5p %c{6}:%L - %m%n
```

instead of

```
appender.console1.layout.pattern = %m%n
```

Below is my java code `GlobalLogger`

```
import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import com.test.sample.common.constants.CommonConstants;
import com.test.sample.obj.ProcessRuntime;

public class GlobalLogger {
    private static final String Ref = ", Ref=";
    private final Logger logger;
    private final Logger testLogger;

    public static GlobalLogger getLogger(Class<?> cls) {
        return getLogger (cls.getName());
    }

    public static GlobalLogger getLogger(String pkgName) {
        return new GlobalLogger(LogManager.getLogger(pkgName));
    }

    private GlobalLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.testLogger=LogManager.getLogger("PERFORMANCE_LOG");
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    
    public static GlobalLogger getTESTLogger(String loggerName) { //1.1
        return new GlobalLogger(LogManager.getLogger(loggerName));
    }

    public void logIbgm(Object message){ //1.1
        testLogger.info("(PERFORMANCE_LOG) " + validateInput(message));
    }
    public boolean isTrace() {
        return logger.isTraceEnabled();
    }

    public void trace(Object message){
        if (isTrace()) {
            logger.trace(lineNumber() + Ref +  (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " +validateInput( message));
        }
    }
    
    public void trace(Object message, Throwable t){
        if(isTrace()){
            logger.trace(lineNumber() + Ref +  (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId()) + ", " + validateInput(message), t);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDebug() {
        return logger.isDebugEnabled();
    }
    
    public void debug(Object message){
        if(isDebug()){
            logger.debug(lineNumber() + Ref +  (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " + validateInput(message));
        }
    }
    
    public void debug(Object message, Throwable t){
        if(isDebug()){
            logger.debug(lineNumber() + Ref + (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " +validateInput( message), t);
        }
    }

    public boolean isInfo() {
         return logger.isInfoEnabled();
    }
    
    public void info(Object message){
        if(isInfo()){
            logger.info(lineNumber() + Ref + (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId()) + ", " +validateInput(message));
        }
    }
    
    public void info(Object message, Throwable t){
        if(isInfo()){
            logger.info(lineNumber() + Ref + (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " + validateInput(message), t);
        }
    }

    public boolean isWarn() {
        return logger.isWarnEnabled();
    }
    
    public void warn(Object message){
        if(isWarn()){
            logger.warn(lineNumber() + Ref +  (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " + validateInput(message));
        }
    }
    
    public void warn(Object message, Throwable t){
        if(isWarn()){
            logger.warn(lineNumber() + Ref + (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " + validateInput(message), t);
        }
    }
    
    public void error(Object message){
        logger.error(lineNumber() + Ref +  (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())+ ", " + validateInput(message));
    }
    
    public void error(Object message, Throwable t){
        logger.error(lineNumber() + Ref + (Objects.equals(null, ProcessRuntime.getRequestId())?"":ProcessRuntime.getRequestId()) + ", " + validateInput(message), t);
    }

    /*
     * Get the Actual Line Number
     */
    private String lineNumber() {
        StackTraceElement[] threadTrackArray = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        if (threadTrackArray.length > 3) {
            return ":" + Integer.toString(threadTrackArray[3].getLineNumber()) + "-";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void consoleLoggerInit () {
        consoleLoggerInit (null);
    }
    public static void consoleLoggerInit (Level logLevel) {
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        if (config != null) {
            config.getRootLogger().getAppenders().clear();
            if (logLevel != null) {
                config.getRootLogger().setLevel(logLevel);
            } else {
                config.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.INFO);
            }
            config.addAppender(ConsoleAppender.createDefaultAppenderForLayout(PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern("%5p [%t] (%c{1}) %m%n")
                    .withConfiguration(config).build()));
        }
    }

    public static String validateInput(Object msg) {
        try {
            String aString="";
            if(msg!=null)
                aString=msg.toString();
            return ESAPI.validator().getValidInput(CommonConstants.ESAPI_CONSTANTS.CONTEXT_INPUT_VALIDATION, aString, 
                    CommonConstants.ESAPI_CONSTANTS.VAL_TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE, aString.length()+1,false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the `this.testLogger=LogManager.getLogger("PERFORMANCE_LOG");` and the method

```
public void logIbgm(Object message){ //1.1
        testLogger.info("(PERFORMANCE_LOG) " + validateInput(message));
    }
```

`PERFORMANCE_LOG is the name that is the same used for the logger name in log4j2.properties`

```
pom.xml

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `appenders` and `loggers` properties to specify the list of appender and logger identifiers. While these properties are still supported, they are not required since version 2.6 (cf. [LOG4J2-1308](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1308)). To enable your "PERFORMANCE_LOG" logger either:

- remove the `loggers` property (by default all the logger ids are enabled),
- **or** set it to a list of all enabled loggers, e.g.:

  ```
  loggers = rolling, performancelog
  ```

**Remark**: while having multiple appenders on the same output stream is allowed, it is certainly not the recommended configuration. The `PatternLayout` in Log4j2 supports "pattern selectors" (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Pattern_Selectors)), which can be used in your scenario.

A possible solution using [`MarkerPatternSelector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#MarkerPatternSelector) would require:

- obviously a marker, e.g.:

  ```java
  private static final Marker PERF_MARKER = MarkerManager.getMarker("PERFORMANCE_LOG");
  ```
- a pattern layout configured with a marker pattern selector:

  ```
  appender.c.l.type = PatternLayout
  appender.c.l.mps.type = MarkerPatternSelector
  appender.c.l.mps.defaultPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %t %-5p %c{6}:%L - %m%n
  appender.c.l.mps.0.type = PatternMatch
  appender.c.l.mps.0.key = PERFORMANCE_LOG
  appender.c.l.mps.0.pattern = (%marker) %m%n
  ```
- to log using the `PERFORMANCE` marker you can use any logger, just use a `Logger` method with a marker parameter or `LogBuilder`:

  ```java
  logger.info(PERF_MARKER, () -> validateInput(message));
  logger.atInfo()
        .withMarker(PERF_MARKER)
        .log("{}", () -> validateInput(message));
  ```